# GNOME screen shield is gone, LXQt and Unity installed after trying GNOME themes

Tags: 18.04, gnome, themes, gnome-shell

After trying some GNOME extensions such as: User themes, Dash to Dock and Blyr and installing GTK3 themes, icon packs, GNOME shell only on GNOME tweak tool, GNOME screen shield is gone.

After logging out it jumps straight into login screen without showing swipe screen with clock. how can i bring it back?

It looks like these themes have installed bunch of desktop-shells somehow. I see in login screen options for Unity, Ubuntu on Wayland, Ubuntu (original one) and LXQt desktops as extra. I am confused and have no idea how they are installed. How can i uninstall them?

This could be helpful:

```
$ aptitude search '~i' -F '%p' | grep wayland
libva-wayland2
libwayland-bin
libwayland-client0
libwayland-client0:i386
libwayland-cursor0
libwayland-dev
libwayland-egl1
libwayland-egl1-mesa
libwayland-server0
libwayland-server0:i386
wayland-protocols
xwayland
```

---

```
$ aptitude search '~i' -F '%p' | grep unity
gir1.2-unity-5.0
libunity-control-center1
libunity-gtk2-parser0
libunity-gtk3-parser0
libunity-protocol-private0
libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop
libunity-settings-daemon1
libunity9
unity-control-center
unity-gtk-module-common
unity-gtk2-module
unity-gtk3-module
unity-services
unity-settings-daemon
```

I have tried following:

- Setting all extension and theme settings back to original and removing them.
- Running system repair in Ubuntu recovery mode
- Reinstalling Ubuntu Desktop using

  ```
  sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
  ```
- Reinstalling GNOME Screensaver using:

  ```
  sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-screen-saver
  ```
- After uninstalling xwayland i wasn't able to log back in so reinstalled that one.
- I was able to remove LXQt and Unity from showing in login screen by

  ```
  apt remove unity-session and apt remove unity
  ```

I have a clean installed Ubuntu 18.04.

Edit: After making some research on internet i figured out that ubuntu on wayland is comming with the ubuntu installation and not installed as a 3rd party app.

Comment: Since you installed Unity, there are chances that login screen would have changed. How does the login screen looks like? Like [this](https://aozoeky4dglp5sh0-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/ubuntu-1710-gdm-login-screen-default.jpg) or [this](https://vitux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/word-image-109-768x432.png)?

Comment: You mention loading themes, icon packs and doing something with Gnome-shell - can you explain what you did?

Comment: @Kulfy: lock screen didn't changed to unity it is still gnome.

Comment: @Charles Green: I have copied some gnome-shell themes and gtk3 themes into .themes folder and choosed them in gnome tweak tool and icons similarly into .icons folder in home directory nothing else. I wasn't able to cicate two users at the same time, sorry if am mistaking.

Comment: No problem - I am just interested in how Unity and LXQt became installed

Comment: That is the main reason i am posting this since it is really strange. I am sure I did not installed them myself:). Worth to mention: I have tried them and LXQt wasnt working. I was getting a black screen with a message which was saying i had to chose something and there wasn't anything to choose in the menu. Unity was working fine meaning it was installed properly. I have get rid of lockscreen entry by running apt remove unity*

Comment: I *think* LQXt requires `lightdm` as the display manager, but others would know better than i.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the output of the following:  `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen`  The bit with the "clock" comes from the Gnome Lock screen, and it can be reset through various themes.